# How to handle button click event in program.cs in C#

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application, buttonclick, mouseclick-event

I have two forms i.e. Form A and Form B. If Button X of Form A is clicked only then Form B will show and Form A will hide. I have to do all this in program.cs of a windows Form Application.

Here is the code snipped

```
            FormA A = new FormA ();
            FormB B = new FormB ();

            A.Show();                    
            if(Button in form A is clicked then )
                  B.Show() and A.hide();
            else 
                  application.close()
```

Comment: Could you show more about the point where you are using this code? Is it inside the Main function?

Comment: Yes Exactly Steve. It is inside the  private static void Main() { ............... } block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing required is to have the button visible outside the form class.
This is done setting the Modifier property in the WinForms Designer to public, or, if you create the button programmatically, you need to declare the variable public at the form level.

Now, with the button public you could write an event handler for its click event and write that handler inside the Program.cs class.
This also requires that your FormA and FormB variables are usable inside the event handler of the button, so you need to have also them public.

```
public static class Program
{
    static FormA A;
    static FormB B;

    public static void Main()
    { 

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        A = new FormA();
        B = new FormB();
        A.Button1.Click += onClick;    

        // This should show the A instance
        Application.Run(A);
        ....
    }
    public static void onClick(oject sender, EventArgs)
    {
        A.Hide();
        B.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will mark it correct as soon as it works :)

Comment: Steve, Are you sure we can access static class event like you did in the answer ?

Comment: Sorry, written by hand and forget to add _static_ to the event handler

Comment: Thanks you are genius but one thing, is there any other way to beside Application.Run for FormA. This is only because I have to start a kernel using application run after run. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I am not sure to understand your request. Application.Run is required to setup all the machinery behind the winforms engine. Without it I am not sure you can run the app at all unless you use ShowDialog (but it is blocking) Probably it is best if you post a new question detailing your requirements in this area.

Comment: Thanks for your comment telling me how to accept the answer and yes you are right I should question with some more details :) thanks